# Lotus Notes 8.0.2 - how to stop all mail showing in customized view

Tags: lotus-notes

I am using Lotus Notes 8.0.2 at work and unfortunately the admin restricted changing default folders design. Only little changes are possible (e.g. change columns order) and even them are resetted each time I restart the client.

I've created a new view with my desired column order, changed sorting etc. I have only one problem - even though I changed the "view" preference to show messages from the inbox folder only, I keep seeing all mail, regardless of the folder they are placed into.

I'm not a Lotus expert and don't really know how to code.

Yet, I am surprised as I see in a "simple view" this:
 uses '(ChangeMeetingType), ...' form  AND  In folder 'Inbox'

And in Formula view only this:

> SELECT ((Form = "(ChangeMeetingType)") | (Form = "(Return Receipt)") |
>   (Form = "Return Receipt") | (Form = "(ReturnNonReceipt)") | (Form =
>   "ReturnNonReceipt") | (Form = "Memo") | (Form = "Memo") | (Form =
>   "MemoEA") | (Form = "Reply") | (Form = "Reply") | (Form = "Reply With
>   History") | (Form = "Reply With History") | (Form = "To Do") | (Form =
>   "Task") | (Form = "_Document Memo") | (Form = "$DocMemo") | (Form =
>   "Word. Document$Word Memo") | (Form = "WordPro. Document$Word Pro Memo")
>   | (Form = "AlternateMemo"))

Therefore, it looks like no folder has been really selected.

How can I create a solution to see:

1. Inbox contents only?
2. Just messages, invitations and other "normal" stuff - without calendar entries and contacts?

Answer (score 0):

It's not trivial to achieve that a view shows folder's documents.
Folders don't have selection formula, Domino server's mail router task "manually" puts all incoming e-mails in the Inbox folder.

You would have to create an agent that would act "After new mail has arrived" and flag those messages (e.g. set field isInInbox to "1").
That's easy, the trickier bit would be to remove that flag when a doc is removed from the Inbox.
To handle drag and drop from the Inbox I'd use Database script's Postdragdrop event to remove the flag.

Then, in your view, you would set simple selection formula, like:

```
SELECT isInInbox != ""
```

Answer (score 0):

[meta: This question is showing up as new/updated?]

Mail files have folders and views. The view will use a selection formula to determine what it is you are looking at.

A folder on the other hand does not have as selection formula. The inBox uses a folder, not a view and there isn't an easy way to create a view that says only show inBox documents.

A better solution for you would be to create a folder, and then mail rules which add the document to the folder if it meets the criteria you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you do create-->view, make sure the 'copy style from view' lists Inbox. You shouldn't have to do anything with the selection criteria, assuming your preferences are already set to not show calendar items in the inbox.

You can have it remove processed calendar items from your inbox instead of just hiding them or showing them all the time.  Preferences-->calendar&todo--> display-->notices.  Check the 'remove meeting notices from my inbox after I process them.'

You can remove existing meeting things from your inbox by clicking on them and doing view-->remove from view, this will keep them in your mailfile in 'all documents' but no in the the inbox or whichever view you choose to remove them from.

If you do want to explicitly block calendar items using a selection formula, they are of type 'notice' and 'appointment'.

Since this is an older question, please let us know if you are still having problems or if you've gotten this resolved.